# Finding a string / array in part of a string

Tags: mysql

This is an example of what my table consists of:

```
groupCanSee
1
1,2
-1,2
```

I have then got an array (detailing the groups that that member is a part of), which I have converted into a string - But could be left as an array.

I have tried to use `FIND_IN_SET(groupsCanSee, $usersGroups)` - But the problem I am of course having, is that the `FIND_IN_SET` function, can only spot 1 part of a string (e.g. 1 in 1,2) but if I want it to be visible to groups 1 and 4 `(FIND_IN_SET('1,4','1,2'))` it will not work.

Does anyone have any suggestions on a workaround?

Comment: What is your desired result for the example data?

Comment: The best advice is to normalize your table. ;)

Comment: The desired result for this data is to form a menu, with some areas being restricted depending on the group that the user is a member of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple boolean logic:

```
FIND_IN_SET(groupsCanSee, `1`) OR FIND_IN_SET(groupsCanSee, `4`)
```

Comment: How can I do this with a string though - I have $userGroups="1,2,3" etc - Yet this would require me doing it for everyone of these?

Comment: @Daniel: Yes. Split them up at source. This is why you should not be using strings for this sort of collated data. NORMALIZE.